# How to colour specific lines in ggtree/ggplot2 plot using geom_line?

Tags: r, ggplot2, phylogeny, ggtree

How do I colour specific lines joined by taxa?

The lines connect through matching tip labels on individual trees and I want to colour the lines via pre defined groups. e.g G1, G2 etc.

I have been following this guide: [guide](https://xiayh17.gitee.io/treedata-book/chapter2.html#data-integration)
I have managed to create a test figure that using the following:

```
library(ape)
library(tidytree)
library(phytools)
library(dplyr)
library(ggtree)
library(ggplot2)

noroot_tree1 <- read.tree("1_HAgenotyping.aln.fasta.treefile.nwk")
noroot_tree2 <- read.tree("8_NAgenotyping.aln.fasta.treefile.nwk")
noroot_tree3 <- read.tree("7_NSgenotyping.aln.fasta.treefile.nwk")

x <- midpoint.root(noroot_tree1)
y <- midpoint.root(noroot_tree2)
z <- midpoint_root(noroot_tree3)

p1 <- ggtree(x)
p2 <- ggtree(y)

d1 <- p1$data
d2 <- p2$data

d2 <- fortify(y)
d3 <- fortify(z)

d2$x <- d2$x + max(d1$x) + 1
d3$x <- d3$x + max(d2$x) + 1

dd = bind_rows(d1, d2, d3) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(label))

p1 + geom_tree(data = d2) + geom_tree(data = d3) + 
  geom_line(aes(x, y, group=label, color=node), data=dd, alpha=.3)
```

[output of above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyXro.jpg)

This has produced a tibble format for the phylogeny as shown below

[example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fqtc4.jpg)

As you can see in the table the Labels start with G1|, G2| etc. is there a way to add a 'group' heading to this table and colour by group?

I have attempted to edit the color section of `geom_line(aes(x, y, group=label, color=node), data=dd, alpha=.3)` as the tutorial uses `geom_line(aes(x, y, group=label, color=node < 15), data=dd, alpha=.3)` to colour based on Node but this does like plotting multiple ranges of node numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should create a new column for the colors.

But a hacky way to do it would be:

```
number_of_interest <- c(5, 8, 14)
p1 + geom_tree(data = d2) + geom_tree(data = d3) + 
  geom_line(aes(x, y, group=label, color=node %in% number_of_interest),
            data=dd, alpha=.3)
```

Your legend will look very strange. To fix it, add the following:

```
scale_color_discrete(name='Node of interest')
```

Comment: Thank you, this does allow me to select specific nodes which is helpful in the scenario I only need 2 colours. 
is there a way to specify specific colours for the selected nodes so overlay by calling geom_line multiple times to view 3+ groups?

Comment: In any case I'd recommend you to create a new column in your `dd` dataset. You may want to have a look at the function `cut`, if you're interested in a certain continuous range of node numbers. If you're interested in very specific nodes, I'm afraid you'll need to use `ifelse` or `dplyr::case_when`.